# get the actual clicked button attributes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I am trying to preview an image before uploading it to server, so below is the html code

```
<html>
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
    {.......}}

$("#selectedFile").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
}); 
</script>

<body>

  <input id="selectedFile" type="file" name="banner_image"/>

  <input type="button" value="Upload image"   onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" class="btn btn-large big_btn"/>

</body>
</html>
```

According to my form design functionality I need to click a button to upload a file to server as above and from that I am clicking the input file field value and sending that file field data to `readURL()` function above.

So when I tried to get the id, name, value attributes in `change` function I am getting the attributes of `input file field`, so can I able to get the values of button attributes in the change function?

Comment: why do you need a change handler if you want to upload only on click of the button

Comment: Actually i am using django(python), so i will get that file field from server, and i will hide that field on the front end(because it does n't) fit to my design, so implemented a button and when a user clicks on the button i activated the hidden file field click

Comment: So now i will have two button 1. Upload button 2. Change button, so when user clicks on upload button i need to do some div operations, and similarly for when a user clicks on change button, so is it possible to get the first clicked button attributes in selectedFile chage fucntion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store the clicked button in a global variable

```
var clickedBtn = null;

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
    {
        alert(input);
    }
}

$("#selectedFile").change(function(){
    if (clickedBtn != null)
    {
        alert(clickedBtn.attr('class')); // get the class attribute, for example
    }
    readURL(this);
}); 


$('.file-upload-btn').click(function(){
    clickedBtn = $(this);
    $("#selectedFile").click();
});
```

Then in your HTML you should remove the onclick attribute from your buttons and add the file-upload-btn class